# Invoke list of function with parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list that has many function with parameter.How can i loop in list and invoke all of the functions in the list?

```
 list= [];
```

and then i push many function in individualWidgetList;

```
 list.push(loadPhoneWidget);
 list.push(loadEmailWidget);
 list.push(loadAgentWidget);
 list.push(loadClientWidget);
```

now i want invoke the functions

```
 for (var i = 0; i < individualWidgetList.length; i++) {

   invoke here    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < individualWidgetList.length; i++) {
     individualWidgetList[i](myParameters);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the objects in the list are functions.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < individualWidgetList.length; i++) {
   individualWidgetList[i](/*Any Parameters*/);    
 }
```

Comment: @Cerbrus your one step ahead of me